# How do I get an Android Process running with the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an Android activity utilizing a JNI library that uses netlink commands to configure a network interface (in this case a socketcan interface).  If I run the activity, the network interface configuration fails with an **EPERM** error from RTNETLINK.  The commands that are failing require the **CAP_NET_ADMIN** capability in order to successfully complete.  As such running the code as root succeeds, and also running as root and then limiting the capabilities to only **CAP_NET_ADMIN** using **capset**.

I added the following permissions to the applications manifest that gave me the impression that my process would be given the NET_ADMIN capabilities:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_ADMIN" />
```

This put the process in the **inet** and **net_admin** groups, but the process did not receive the CAP_NET_ADMIN capability resulting in the netlink commands failing with EPERM.

In various searches I have made on this topic I have found hints that the capability should be applied. eg, from http://elinux.org/Android_Security

```
#define             GID     Capability
AID_NET_BT_ADMIN    3001    Can create an RFCOMM, SCO, or L2CAPP Bluetooth socket
AID_NET_BT          3002    Can create a Bluetooth socket
AID_INET            3003    Can create IPv4 or IPv6 socket
AID_NET_RAW         3004    Can create certain kinds of IPv4 sockets??
AID_NET_ADMIN*      3005    Allow CAP_NET_ADMIN permissions for process
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to apply to my system.

NOTE: I am running with a system and kernel modified by a chipset vendor, so it is possible that something has been modified that stops this from working.

Does anyone know

- If this should *just work*?
- What other steps are required to add the capability to a process?
- Whether it is even possible?

Comment: How did you assign the `NET_ADMIN` permission to your app? Was it signed with the same keys used for the firmware? During installation of the APK on an Android 4.3 device, the permission was removed. Running the command `pm grant <package name> android.permission.NET_ADMIN` (as root) errors out with *Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.NET_ADMIN is not a changeable permission type*.

Comment: To answer my own question, I reinstalled firmware with my newly created keys without wiping `/data`. This resulted in the old certificates still being used (`/data/system/packages.xml`). After replacing the four certificates (platform, media, shared, testkey) in recovery and rebooting, I got the permission when signing the APK with my platform key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that Android modifies the kernel capability system to allow verification of specific capabilities based on group-id.  Unfortunately the modifications made don't seem to cover all cases.  To resolve the problem I was having, I modified the **cap_netlink_recv** check to use the Android modified **cap_capability** call.  This allows users in the net_link group to obtain **CAP_NET_LINK** capabilities.

This change seems to be within the spirit of the modifications made to the Android kernel, and works for my situation.

```
diff --git a/security/commoncap.c b/security/commoncap.c
        index ccfe568..f069f8d 100644
        --- a/security/commoncap.c
        +++ b/security/commoncap.c
        @@ -56,21 +56,23 @@
    }
}

int cap_netlink_send(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)
{
» return 0;
}

int cap_netlink_recv(struct sk_buff *skb, int cap)
{
-» if (!cap_raised(current_cap(), cap))
+» if (cap_capable(current, current_cred(),
+» » » current_cred()->user->user_ns, cap,
+» » » SECURITY_CAP_NOAUDIT) != 0)
» » return -EPERM;
» return 0;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(cap_netlink_recv);

/**
 * cap_capable - Determine whether a task has a particular effective capability
 * @tsk: The task to query
 * @cred: The credentials to use
 * @ns:  The user namespace in which we need the capability
```

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, in the netlink path, there is no check for additional permissions *for kernel versions before [v3.1-18-gfd77846](https://git.kernel.org/linus/fd778461524849afd035679030ae8e8873c72b81)*.

Originally it did not seem to be a good idea to replace `cap_raised` completely, so here I chose to prepend a similar check as the one in `cap_capable`. Other possible `cap`s are `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, `CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL` and `CAP_AUDIT_WRITE`, but these are not relevant to networking. Note that since the above commit, it ultimately ends up calling `cap_capable` (via `capable`).

The patch:

```diff
diff --git a/security/commoncap.c b/security/commoncap.c
index 8bfbd13..485245a 100644
--- a/security/commoncap.c
+++ b/security/commoncap.c
@@ -63,6 +63,10 @@ int cap_netlink_send(struct sock *sk, struct sk_buff *skb)

 int cap_netlink_recv(struct sk_buff *skb, int cap)
 {
+#ifdef CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK
+   if (cap == CAP_NET_ADMIN && in_egroup_p(AID_NET_ADMIN))
+       return 0;
+#endif
    if (!cap_raised(current_cap(), cap))
        return -EPERM;
    return 0;
```

For those looking at `CAP_NET_RAW`, for that you need to be in the `net_raw` group. Either add that group to the existing `android.permission.NET_ADMIN` permission or apply the following framework patch:

```
diff --git a/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml b/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml
index 1e7dcf7..07f5d94 100644
--- a/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml
+++ b/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml
@@ -927,6 +927,12 @@
         android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
         android:protectionLevel="signature" />

+    <!-- Allows access to raw sockets, allowing full network access and spoofing.
+         @hide -->
+    <permission android:name="android.permission.NET_RAW"
+        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
+        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
+
     <!-- Allows registration for remote audio playback. @hide -->
     <permission android:name="android.permission.REMOTE_AUDIO_PLAYBACK"
         android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.SYSTEM_TOOLS"
diff --git a/data/etc/platform.xml b/data/etc/platform.xml
index 47cb7ab..9c209c3 100644
--- a/data/etc/platform.xml
+++ b/data/etc/platform.xml
@@ -82,6 +82,10 @@
         <group gid="net_admin" />
     </permission>

+    <permission name="android.permission.NET_RAW" >
+        <group gid="net_raw" />
+    </permission>
+
     <!-- The group that /cache belongs to, linked to the permission
          set on the applications that can access /cache -->
     <permission name="android.permission.ACCESS_CACHE_FILESYSTEM" >
```