# SocketBuildError: Permission Denied for raw sockets

Tags: android, flutter, networking, rust

I was asked to adapt our network testing libraries so that they are able to run on Android.
The application's base functionalities are written in Rust and include `ping`, `dns`, `traceroute`, etc.

I'll use ping as an example, but the same problem applies to other applications that rely on the creation of a raw socket. For instance, performing a DNS query using a standard UDP socket works without any problems.
The framework used for the actual Android app is Flutter.
For now, all tests were done using the Android Emulator inside Android Studio 2021.0.1 Patch 2.
As emulator images go, I tried on:

- Android 12.0 x86_64 (API31)
- Android 7 x86 (API24)
- Android 7 armeabi-v7a (API24)
- Android 11 arm64-v8a (API30)

I created a [git repo](https://github.com/fabracht/flutter_rust_project_1) with a minimal example of the entire application, in case anyone wants to test it out.
I'm binding Rust with Flutter using the [Flutter Bridge](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rust_bridge) Dart package. (Also in case you want to reproduce the bindings yourself).

The demo application is super simple and tries to focus on the problem at hand, which seems to be the creation of the RAW socket.
While searching for the solution, I've stumbled across a lot of information and I'm not entirely sure what's still relevant (mostly up to date) or not.
When searching for how to create a raw socket with an application built with NDK, I found this:
https://android-developers.narkive.com/BK5uGK4f/android-ndk-raw-socket-creation-problem

The author seems to have the same problem and the answer points out that this would not be possible because the application needs root access.
So, I tried doing `adb root && adb remount`. When I run `adb shell`, I'm given the root shell (#), and running `tcpdump` (which needs all types of access possible for network), seems to work.
Obviously, simply doing `adb root` did not fix my problem and the application (`flutter run`) still results in:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: FfiException(PANIC_ERROR, called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 1, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Operation not permitted" }, null)
```

So, my first thought was that the emulator was not rooted, or something like that, but after some research, I found out that, not only the device has to be rooted, but your app needs to ask for root access itself. So, I tried using this Dart library:
[Root Access Plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/root_access)
That didn't work as well. The root access gets denied. This library uses a method that is similar to what's described in [this Stack Overflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905743/android-how-to-gain-root-access-in-an-android-application).
In order to provide an application with root capabilities, you need to call the application preceded by `su`.
I haven't tried creating a binary from the Rust library and calling it manually with `su`, mainly because I just couldn't get the cross-compilation to work for the target x86_64 Android architecture (but this is another very lengthy discussion).

In Linux, you can set the capabilities of the binary with `setcap`. For raw sockets, a simple `setcap cap_net_raw+ep [binary]` solves the issue. Of course, you need root or `sudo` for that. In Android, from my understanding, capabilities work differently. Here's a [Stack Overflow posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042117/how-do-i-get-an-android-process-running-with-the-cap-net-admin-capability) that touches this subject.
It suggests that you can change the app's capabilities by requesting them in your manifest file. It didn't seem to work for me, but I'm not so sure I did that correctly.
For the emulator, I added

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NET_RAW" />
```

to the `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

#### SUMMARY

From my Flutter application, I want to be able to call my linked Rust library (compiled .so files), and the Rust code needs to have access to raw sockets.
So, how can I make this work?

Comment: Note that the Android SDK emulators are not rooted by default, so calling `su` won't work anyway.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion: an Android app never runs with root permissions. It can ask for root permissions and if granted execute an executable with root permissions but the app and their libraries stay in non-root state.

Comment: Thanks for the information. So one solution would be creating an executable and running it with su on a rooted real device (no emulator)?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: For Android apps gaining Linux capabilities isn't an option. So you can't use RAW / PACKET sockets, you can't  listen on ports under 1024, and so on. There are many ongoing debates in Google issue tracker for over a decade like [this one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36909525). // But for `ping` at least you can use DATAGRAM socket instead of RAW, like `int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP);`. That's how Android's `ping` works without privileges. See some limitations [here](https://github.com/iputils/iputils/blob/20211215/ping/ping.c#L93).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Indeed, I had already seen this discussion. The problem I have is that our application monitors things that are in the IP packet, such as dscp, the ip checksum, etc. When you set the socket to DGRAM, you lose access to that layer.

Comment: Then build your Rust library as a binary and run it as a separate process with root privileges. Do IPC between the app and the privileged process.